# TFS 2008 Testing of Builds

Tags: tfs

This is my first at doing any sort of builds period.  Unfortunately we're using TFS 2008 (I like Subversion better overall in its use because it is just as powerful and simpler to use as most good developers are quite aware of).  But anyway, how can you test a build when you only have a dev server and no staging server?  I want to test to make sure the build works both server-side and client-side by testing the website.  Can you essentially use your dev server as a staging server so that when you run the build against your prod environment there are no surprises thereof?

Comment: Don't talk down to the technology you're using - if you don't like it, convince your team to use another. It's not going to get your question answered.

Comment: If you don't know the basics of the tool you're using, as your question suggests, it's generally best to keep quiet about what you think is better.  This isn't even a TFS-specific question, I would think it would apply to whatever build environment one might choose.

Answer (score 1):

just set up your tests to deploy (what that means in your environment) as you see fit and run tests.